# How to handle mutation GraphQL error instead of Apollo onError()

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, graphql, apollo

Server side, I am throwing a 403 Forbidden, to manage access to an API call.

To catch the GraphQL error for a mutation, I've tried the following: (method #1 is working when catching errors for `useQuery()`)

```
const [m, { error }] = useMutation(MY_MUTATION);

if(error) {
    console.error('Error return #1');
}

try {
  await m({
    variables,
    onError: (e: ApolloError) => {
       console.error('Error return #2');
    }
  }).catch(e) {
     console.error('Error return #3');
  };
} catch (e) {
    console.error('Error return #4');
}
```

Instead, from my Apollo `onError()`, the following GraphQL errors are returned and the execution stops. It does not go into any of my mutation error handling attempts:

```
graphQLErrors:, Array [
  Object {
    "extensions": Object {
      "code": "FORBIDDEN",
      "response": Object {
        "error": "Forbidden",
        "message": "Access is denied.",
        "statusCode": 403,
      },
    },
    "message": "Access is denied.",
  },
]
```

If a similar GraphQL error is returned from `useQuery()`, it shows it using:

```
const { data, error, loading } = useQuery( MY_QUERY );

if(error) {
    console.error('Error return #1');
}
```

Comment: You need to be much more specific in what you want, because the type of error you will catch in #1 is different than what you will catch elsewhere.  The code you have will work fine for the types of errors #1 will catch, which you do not specify.  If you want all errors caught like #1, there is no solution.  `useMutation` doesn't make connections to see the 403 response until you `await m`.  It will *never* be able to catch that error above universally because what may cause that condition is dynamic in time.

Comment: @possum I updated the question according to your feedback

Answer (score 1):

Based on [useMutation documentation](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/mutations/#usemutation-api) I believe `mutate` (or `m`) function doesn't accept `onError` callback and you have to set it in `useMutation` options.

```js
const [m, { error }] = useMutation(MY_MUTATION, {
  onError: (e: ApolloError) => {
     console.error('Error return #2');
  }
});

if (error) {
    console.error('Error return #1');
}

try {
  await m({
    variables
  })
} catch (e) {
    console.error('Error return #4');
}
```

Comment: Interesting observation! However, the same issue still persists after moving the `onError()` method